# How to load script using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-component

I have a problem loading a javascript using a XMLHttpRequest.
I am using a node server for local development.
For creating the request I use

```
const request: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = RSLImport.moduleOnLoaded.bind(request, this);
request.open('GET', `${url}`);
request.responseType = 'document';
request.send();
```

where `RSLImport.moduleOnLoaded` is the callback that receives the document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="module1/module1.css">
<script src="module1/module1.js" type="module"></script>
<template id="module1">
    <p>Module 1</p>
</template>
```

In the callback I append received nodes

```
    const elements = request.responseXML?.head.children;
    if (elements){
        console.log(elements[1].baseURI);
        document.head.append(...elements);
    }
```

All node are inserted into the DOM document head and the stylesheet is properly loaded but the javascript isn't.

If I create a script documet element using `createElement('script')`, set its `src` and `type` properties and append it to the document head it loads the script correctly.

Could anyone help me understand appending received nodes doesn't load the javascript?

To explain my use case I try writing an custom web component that imports other custom web components via their html.

Comment: Isn't this the classic 'hacker' XSS (Cross Site Scripting) scenario?

Comment: Not sure, but the main page and the imported document/script are on the same site/domain (localhost server).